# Elasticsearch - corpus size / overall term frequency

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to get the corpus size of a field in a subset of my data? In other words, I want to count all words of a certain field. The words are in documents, which satisfy a query conditon.

This information is provided by term vectors. Term vectors could be applied on particular documents, but not on multiple documents. [Multi-term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html) allow to specify a list of document-ids to retrieve each term vector statistic for each term in each document. Unfortunately they are not aggregated, I have to aggregate them by myself.

Is there a more elastic way, to achieve a aggregated term statistic? Could I use [groovy scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) to aggregate term vectors?

**Solution:**
@Val, thanks for the solution. The query for all documents with `my_int_value=1` looks like:

```
GET /index/type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "my_int_value": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "counting" : {
      "sum" : {
        "field" : "your_field.word_count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you only need *distinct words* in a field, you could use the [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html) to approximate this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you care about is the number of tokens/words in the field, you can also declare a [`token_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#token_count) sub-field in your string field. Your mapping would look like this:

```
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "your_field" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "fields" : {
                    "word_count": {
                        "type" : "token_count",
                        "store" : "yes",
                        "analyzer" : "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your queries you can refer to the `your_field.word_count` field to get the number of tokens/words available in `your_field`.